# How to elegantly wrap overloaded methods in java?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

For example, there are some overloaded methods `setData(T data)` where `T` can be `Something.Builder` or `Something` (there is no common interface implemented by both of them or `setData` won't accept the common interface as its parameter).

The following code will work but introduce duplicated code.

```
public void setSomething(Something.Builder data) {
    thirdPartyLib.setData(data);
    ...
    cache = null;
}

public void setSomething(Something data) {
    thirdPartyLib.setData(data);
    ...
    cache = null;
}
```

Are there any better choices?

For instance, we can merge them into one function template in C++:

```
template<typename T>
void setSomething(T data) {
    thirdPartyLib.setData(data);
    ...
    cache = null;
}
```

But how can we do it in java?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `thirdPartyLib.setData(data)` has (at least) two overloaded versions, one for `Something`, and one for `Something.Builder`.

In Java, overloaded methods are completely distinct from one another, just happen to have the same name. You get exactly the same behavior if one is called `setSomethingData(Something data)`, and the other `setSomethingBuilderData(Something.Builder data)`. You can't write down a single call that switches between the two versions at runtime.

So at least for the `setData()` call, your code needs to have two separate statements. And then I see three approaches:

- Stay with your duplicated `setSomething()` methods as given in the question. That's quite ok if it's just a handful of lines common to the two methods.
- Have two `setSomething()` methods, but refactor the common parts into some helper method. I'd do that if there's more lines of common code.
- Have one `setSomething(Object data)` method that decides internally which `setData()` version to call, using `instanceof` tests and casts. I'd avoid that like the plague, as it moves type-checking out of the compile-time into run-time.

After discussing your explicit question, let me ask if you really want to pass builders around instead of "real" objects. That's not what builders were typically meant for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The overloaded `setData()` methods are the code generated by Google's protobuf compiler (v3.5.1). I want to write a wrapper to cache the serialized stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics in that case.
Hope this helps

---

```
public <T> void setSomething(T data) {
    thirdPartyLib.setData(data);
        ...
        cache = null;

    }
```

Comment: Probably this won't work, as the OP stated that the `setData()` method won't accept a common interface as parameter, and your version assumes that there is a `setData(Object)` method.

Comment: I just gave the solution on how the original code is written.
If that is the case, then we'll have to change the implementation if the requirement is more clear

Comment: I've tried something like `public <T extends A> void setSomething(T data)`. However, there could be one class after `extends` only, while there are two classes (`Something` and `Something.Builder`) in my case.

Comment: Create one abstract class or interface which is extended/implemented by Somethin and Something.Builder. Let me know what you did. I am just shooting in the air